# Standard Error of a linear regression

Tags: correlation, variance, standard-error, covariance

As defined [here](http://www.zoology.ubc.ca/~whitlock/bio300/overheads/overheads16.pdf), the estimation of the coefficient of correlation is

$$r = \frac{\Sigma (X_i-E[X])(Y_i-E[Y])}{\sqrt { \Sigma (X_i-E[X])^2 \Sigma (Y_i - E[Y])^2}}$$

and the standard error of $r$ is

$$SE_r = \sqrt{\frac{1-r^2}{n-2}}$$

**How was $SE_r$ calculated?**

Comment: I believe that particular formula is based on regression calculations.

Comment: In particular, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient#Testing_using_Student.27s_t-distribution)